# JSON to PHP Error

Tags: php, json

My JSON file is in the following format:

```
{
    "library": [{
        "image": "css/covers/rainbow6siege.jpg",
        "title": "Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six: Siege",
        "system": ["PC", "Xbox-360", "Xbox One", "PS4"],
        "genre": ["Shooter"],
        "pegi_rating": "18",
        "developer": "Ubisoft",
        "release_year": "2015",
        "max_team": "5"
    }, {
        "image": "css/covers/thedivision.jpg",
        "title": "Tom Clancy's The Division",
        "system": ["PC", "Xbox-360", "Xbox One", "PS4"],
        "genre": ["Shooter", "MMO", "Action RPG"],
        "pegi_rating": "15",
        "developer": "Ubisoft",
        "release_year": "2016",
        "max_team": "3"
    }]
}
```

I've connected to the database, got the contents of the file, decoded it and trying to assign each variable to its associated JSON variable. Using the code:

```
  $jsonData = file_get_contents('js/json/library.json');
  $data = json_decode($jsonData, true);

  $gameImage = $data['image'];
```

I've only used one as a example but I get the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\MAMP\htdocs\iniDb.php on line 21
```

I don't understand where I am going wrong.

Comment: `print_r($data);` to see.

Comment: `json_last_error()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

Comment: probably `$data['library'][0]['image'];`

Comment: @AbraCadaver having done that, I see that arrays within arrays but still don't understand why assigning the image is throwing the error?
Do I need to use a loop to work through the JSON array?

I am using the following example as guidance, 
[link[(http://www.kodingmadesimple.com/2014/12/how-to-insert-json-data-into-mysql-php.html)

Comment: @Pitchinnate getting 0

Comment: @JacksonJacob then that means it parsed it correctly, look at Lashane's answer you are referencing the value incorrectly

Comment: @Lashane Thank you! It was that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your $data is a multidimensional array that consists of associative array on the first level ('library' key) and two numeric arrays on the second (0 and 1 are your keys).
Code below should do:

```
$data['library'][0]['image']
```

Answer (score 0):

Once decoded your JSON, thanks to the `, true` option you used, the resulting output looks like this:

```
$data = [
  "library" => [
    [
        "image" => "css/covers/rainbow6siege.jpg",
        "title" => "Tom Clancy's Rainbow Six => Siege",
        "system" => ["PC", "Xbox-360", "Xbox One", "PS4"],
        "genre" => ["Shooter"],
        "pegi_rating" => "18",
        "developer" => "Ubisoft",
        "release_year" => "2015",
        "max_team" => "5"
    ],
    [
        "image" => "css/covers/thedivision.jpg",
        "title" => "Tom Clancy's The Division",
        "system" => ["PC", "Xbox-360", "Xbox One", "PS4"],
        "genre" => ["Shooter", "MMO", "Action RPG"],
        "pegi_rating" => "15",
        "developer" => "Ubisoft",
        "release_year" => "2016",
        "max_team" => "3"
    ]
  ]
]
```

From that it becomes obvious that `$data['image']` can't be found!

You have to do something like this:

```
foreach ($data as $member) {
  foreach ($member['library'] as $library) {
    foreach ($library as $element) {
      echo $element['image'];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wander why this downvote. My answer may be wrong, but anybody thinking so must at least explain why!

Comment: It seems, topic starter needs very simplified answer to use as ready-n-go solution right now. Compensated.

Comment: @Wizard I see what you mean. But the OP said he wants "to assign _each variable_ to its associated JSON variable", then added "I've only used one as a example": all that leads to think he needed to iterate. Anyay, much thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate through the decoded json array collection, this is how you do it:

```
// your json here
$data = json_decode('{
    "library": [{
        "image": "css/covers/rainbow6siege.jpg",
        "title": "Tom Clancy\'s Rainbow Six: Siege",
        "system": ["PC", "Xbox-360", "Xbox One", "PS4"],
        "genre": ["Shooter"],
        "pegi_rating": "18",
        "developer": "Ubisoft",
        "release_year": "2015",
        "max_team": "5"
    }, {
        "image": "css/covers/thedivision.jpg",
        "title": "Tom Clancy\'s The Division",
        "system": ["PC", "Xbox-360", "Xbox One", "PS4"],
        "genre": ["Shooter", "MMO", "Action RPG"],
        "pegi_rating": "15",
        "developer": "Ubisoft",
        "release_year": "2016",
        "max_team": "3"
    }]
}'
, true);

foreach ($data['library'] as $library)
{
    echo "<pre>";
    foreach ($library as $key => $value)
    {
        echo "<span style='color: #cc0000;'>$key</span> = ";
        echo trim(print_r($value, true)) ."\r\n";
    }
    echo "</pre><hr>";
}
```

Outputs:

[image]

For example, if you want the title of each library item, this what you do:

```
foreach ($data['library'] as $library)
{
    echo "title = ". $library['title'];
}
```